# debug azure webapp using ssh

Tags: debugging, ssh, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a new webapp in azure cloud.

The challenge is that I am working on a new python module that I dont know that well, Pyspice. Pyspice interface to a program Ngpspice.
On my windows PC it works fine but not on the cloud. So I would like to be able to do debugging without pushing and then wait 25min for each build.

Right now I am using SSH to connect to the webapp. Then I can create a simple python script to see if I can get the connection to work between pyspice and ngspice. The challenge I have is that when I run python in SSH then it uses a different environment than the webapp, i.e. all the modules in the requirements.txt is not available. So how can I change environment to be able to debug?

Comment: What is the python version in SSH and the Web App?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Azure App service with Python version 3.8, when I check the version in Azure SSH it is showing me different version.

To install the latest version in Azure SSH, run the below command

```cs
apt update
apt install python3.9
python --version
```

Run the below command to change the python version of the Azure App service in Azure Cloud Shell (Bash).

```cs
az webapp config set --resource-group MyRGName --name WebAppName --linux-fx-version "PYTHON|3.9"
```

[image]
To check the updated version, run the below command

```cs
az webapp config show --resource-group MyRGName --name  Python4Nov --query linuxFxVersion
```

[image]

> debug azure webapp using ssh

To remote debug Azure Linux App Service, we need to open a TCP Tunnel from the development machine to Azure App Service.

***Configure for SSH and Remote Debugging***
In Azure CLI run the below command

```cs
az webapp create-remote-connection --resource-group MyRG -n WebAppName
```

***References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session#open-ssh-session-from-remote-shell)***